# How do extended urls work

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

I know how these kind of URLs load the page ... based on their GET parameter.

http://www.bedupako.com/songs.php?page=show_song_details.php&songid=1167&n=0&back=no

and in the back-end roughly something like this:

```
<?php
switch($_GET['page']) {
case 'xx': include('my page');break;
.
.
.
default: include('default');break;
}
?>
```

But how do these kinds of URLs work? I mean, how is the data loaded dynamically?

```
www.dummysite.com/parm/subpage1/xyz
www.dummysite.com/parm/subpage2/xyz
```

How are these parsed similar to the GET param like websites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mod_rewrite by itself as others have suggested, but most sites do not do this because its not very flexible, and can be annoying to maintain if you have more than a couple of these "pretty" URLS.

Instead they set up a basic rewrite rule to forward everything to a single index.php and then on the application side they parse the URI based on defined patterns - these are called "routes". Route parsing usually happens in some kind of routing class which process the defined routes and compares them to the URI, and then when it finds a match parses out the parameters for the matched route.

These all provide good examples of a router, but they are hard to understand without the other interacting classes:

- Zend: [`Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite`](http://framework.zend.com/code/filedetails.php?repname=Zend+Framework&path=%2Fbranches%2Frelease-1.11%2Flibrary%2FZend%2FController%2FRouter%2FRewrite.php)
- Symfony: [`sfPatternRouting`](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/routing/sfPatternRouting.class.php)
- Cake: [`Router`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/cake/libs/router.php)
- CodeIgniter: [`CI_Router`](https://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter-reactor/src/d406084f5bef/system/core/Router.php)

Answer (score 2):

In most cases this will be handled by the web server on-the-fly according to a set of rules. The specifics of it will vary from server to server and on a case-by-case basis. In Apache it is usually done using [the mod_rewrite extension](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Answer (score 1):

You should look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html url rewriting if you're with apache (most likely)